# concurrent sessions with authentication and mapping cookie to the user to do operations in python

Tags: python-2.7

I developed a webserver using BaseHttpServer module. 
in that i created a login page.html and getting the username and password details and sending to the request = requests.session()
s= request.get(username, password)
print s.text #which is session cookie
I logged in successfully and doing the get, post  operations.
The problem is when other user trying to hit the url after the login page he is accessing my session cookie and doing all operations.
how to restrict that and is there any method of handling multiple user sessions at a time to login to the SSO page which i am calling that url in get method

> import json
>      import getpass
>      import requests
>      from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
>      port = 8000
>      returns

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

```
   Page = '''\   
        # Myloginpage code in html   
        '''   
   get = '''\    
        #My Get login page html Details Form    
        '''   
def _set_headers(self):   
  self.send_response(200)   
  self.send_header("Content-Type","text/html")   
  self.end_headers()       
def do_Get(self):   
  if self.path =='/':   
    self.wfile.write(self.Page) #My login page   
      # Get operations which is working   
def do_POST(self):   
   content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])   
   post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)   
   post_data_tmp =  post_data.split('&')   
   for querystring in post_data_tmp:   
     if 'uname' in querystring:   
       username= querystring.split('=')[1]   
     if 'psw' in querysting:   
       password = querystring.split('=')[1]   
   ssosession = xyz.sso.session(username, password)   
   s = ssosession.get('xyzurl',verify = False)   
   S.cookie = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(ssosession)   
   # I am passing this cookie to connect to the api and get the details   

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class = S, port = port)   
  server_address = ('',port)   
  httpd = server_class(server_address,handler_class)   
  print 'starting httpd...'   
  httpd.serve_forever()   

if __name__="__main__":   
from sys import argv   
if len(argv) = =2:      
  run(port = int(argv[1])   
else:   
  run()
```

when the webbrowser starts i opened the url http://xyz:8080/ then the login page opens which i created in html . after I submit the username and password , those will be stored and send to the SSo login page to get the cookie . with that session i am successfully can play with the browser.
the issue here is when other user hits the url, he is not authenticating and he is able to do the operations with my session.
could anyone suggest me how to create a session for each http request to authenticate.
if second user clicks the login page , he will be logged in . if suppose if he clicks the other page part of this project he is able to access with my session

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this issue.  It also looks like there is code inline with your text. Please pull that out and put it into a code block.

Comment: Hi Zack . I mentioned the code. Please suggest me . Thanks